# Clone a div in another div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs called `.nav-previous` and `.nav-next`
What I wanted to do is have `.nav-previous` at the position of `.nav-next` and `.nav-next` being in `.nav-previous` position.

I've tryed this:

```
var p=$(".nav-previous");
$(".nav-previous") =$(".nav-next");
$(".nav-next")=p;
```

and this:

```
var p=$(".nav-previous");
$(".nav-next").clone().appendTo(".nav-previous").html();
p.clone().appendTo(".nav-next").html();
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<nav class="navigation posts-navigation" role="navigation">
   <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Navigazione articoli</h2>
   <div class="nav-links">
      <div class="nav-previous"><a href="linktopreviouspage.com" >Articoli meno recenti</a></div>
      <div class="nav-next"><a href="linktonextpage.com" >Articoli seguenti</a></div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by switch?

Comment: You  mean toggle between those two divs?

Comment: Dude, "What I wanted to do is have .nav-previous at the position of .nav-next and .nav-next being in .nav-previous position." You want to swap the links or their contents.?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal i want to swap the divs.. Everything. Content and links

Comment: You can either swap the links and copy the contents of that html.But when you click on the a tag  it wil move to the corresponding screen,so you cannot see the swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe copy their html?

```
var temp=$(".nav-previous").html();
$(".nav-previous").html($(".nav-next").html());
$(".nav-next").html(temp);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use various method like [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)/[`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
$(".nav-previous").insertAfter($('.nav-next'))
//$(".nav-previous").appendTo('.nav-links')
//$(".nav-next").after($('.nav-previous'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation posts-navigation" role="navigation">
   <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Navigazione articoli</h2>
   <div class="nav-links">
      <div class="nav-previous"><a href="linktopreviouspage.com" >Articoli meno recenti</a></div>
      <div class="nav-next"><a href="linktonextpage.com" >Articoli seguenti</a></div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this, when you say switch?

```js
$('.nav-previous').insertAfter('.nav-next');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation posts-navigation" role="navigation">
   <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Navigazione articoli</h2>
   <div class="nav-links">
      <div class="nav-previous"><a href="linktopreviouspage.com" >Articoli meno recenti</a></div>
      <div class="nav-next"><a href="linktonextpage.com" >Articoli seguenti</a></div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

  <head>
   <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").clone().appendTo("#target");
    });
});

</script>

  </head>

<body>

 <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>
<div id="target">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

so what we're doing is, on button click `$("button").click(function()` , we're finding the element we want to clone, cloning it `$("p").clone()` and appending it to another element `.appendTo("#target");`. i.e. the div. We give the div that we want to append to an id (`id="target"`) so we can find it from our js script.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Get references of parent divs
var $navPrev = $('.nav-previous');
var $navNext = $('.nav-next');

//Get html contents of parent divs
var navPrevHtml = $navPrev.html();
var navNextHtml = $navNext.html();


//Replace html contents of each parent with contents of the other
$navPrev.html(navNextHtml);
$navNext.html(navPrevHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation posts-navigation" role="navigation">
  <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Navigazione articoli</h2>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <div class="nav-previous"><a href="linktopreviouspage.com">Articoli meno recenti</a></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><a href="linktonextpage.com">Articoli seguenti</a></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Get the html content of nav previous and nav next.

```
var navPrev =$(".nav-previous").html();
var navNext = $(".nav-next").html();
```

**Step 2:**

Set the nav previous to nav next and nav next to nav previous.

```
$(".nav-previous").html(navNext);
$(".nav-next").html(navPrev);
```

Hope it helps.